# Not getting labels in graph in plot() function using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I Tried to plot graph using plot() function in pandas:

```
fd.plot(x= 'values', y='locations', title='Evoqua', kind='hist', figsize=(6,6))
```

but it failed to get labels on x and y axis?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFrame.plot()` method returns a `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` object, so you can add labels to it like in `matplotlib`:

```
ax = fd.plot(x='values', y='locations', title='Evoqua', kind='hist', figsize=(6, 6))

ax.set_xlabel("x label")
ax.set_ylabel("y label")
```